# How to manually install App Engine in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, maven

I just added the App Engine module to my app and upon syncing, gradle started downloading the App Engine zip from maven. App Engine's zip file is about 150mb+ and using maven to automatically download it is painfully slow so I decided to manually download the appengine java sdk (appengine-java-sdk-1.9.6.zip) and manually install it. I have the zip now, but where do I place it so that Android Studio (0.8.1) picks it up and install it instead of trying to download it from maven's repository?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The templates for appengine that ship with android studio download the appengine sdk by default... so if you are using those templates, you have to do the following.

edit the build.gradle file and remove

```
dependencies {
  appengineSdk "com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:X.X.X"  <--- remove
 ...
}
```

and

```
appengine {
  downloadSdk = true <--- remove this line as it tells it to dl the sdk    
}
```

Then you can reference a downloaded sdk using a system property. Create a file in the same directory as your build.gradle file in your appengine module

gradle.properties

```
systemProp.appengine.sdk.root = "path to appengine sdk"
```

There are other ways to specify the location of the sdk (like using an environment variable) that might work better for you, check https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin

Comment: I've implemented this method and now I'm getting "There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib: Read timed out'.

Comment: That is another network command, did it take a long time? Can you run it with --info or --debug or --stacktrace?

Comment: Thanks for your help, it finally downloaded by itself. And, for anyone in the same shoe, it downloads App Engine to the main directory of ".gradle" by default. Extract your files there and locate it in your project.

Comment: @gcmx I think your comment should be and answer to aid easy finding and identification. Thanks

Comment: @gcmx main directory of ".gradle" means the .gradle folder of project or the .gradle folder which is there in C:\Users\XYZ\.gradle ?

Comment: Another example guys:

`systemProp.appengine.sdk.root=C:/<PATH UNTIL BEFORE OF THE FOLDER APP_ENGINE_SDK>/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.40`

In pratice:

`systemProp.appengine.sdk.root=C:/Users/programmer/StudioProjects/MyApplication/.gradle/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.40`

Answer (score 1):

A completely different approach would be be to create a local maven repository for the appengine sdk and reference that directly and leave everything else intact.

```
repositories {
  maven {
    url 'file://path/to/myCustomRepo'
  }
  mavenCentral()
}
```

So this method is easiest if you grab the appengine sdk directly from maven.org because it will be named correctly. (http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.google.appengine|appengine-java-sdk|1.9.6|zip) but chose the version you are referencing in your build file.

About the maven repo, you need to set it up correctly.
If your downloaded zip is in `/path/to/myCustomRepo` you need to actually put the zip in the correct location : `/path/to/myCustomRepo/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.6` depending on the version number you're using.

If you **only have the zip file** in the repository directory you need to modify the `downloadSdk` line to indicate all that is available is the "zip" with the **@zip** modifier.

```
downloadSdk "com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.6@zip"
```

If you don't want to use the **@zip** you can add a simple .pom file (next to the .zip) so the system can correctly determine the reference

appengine-java-sdk-1.9.6.pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-java-sdk</artifactId>
  <packaging>zip</packaging>
  <version>1.9.6</version>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, SOLVED!

Set the path of app engine SDK in file called gradle.properties:

`systemProp.appengine.sdk.root=C:/<PATH UNTIL BEFORE OF THE FOLDER APP_ENGINE_SDK>/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.40`

Example:

`systemProp.appengine.sdk.root=C:/Users/programmer/StudioProjects/MyApplication/.gradle/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.40`

Edit the build.gradle file and change to false the following line:

`appengine {
  downloadSdk = false
}`