# Unable to download appengine sdk inside Android Studio

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio

As per [this](https://cloud.google.com/mobile/app_engine/add_module) tutorial, I tried adding app engine module in my android application on android studio.
But when the project sync starts up, it starts downloading app-engine sdk which is taking infinite time to download

Also after a very long time, sync failed and unable to download errors come up

---

Error:Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':backend:appengineSdk'.
Could not download artifact 'appengine-java-sdk.zip (com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.14)'
Failed to download resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.14/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.14.zip'.
Connection reset

---

I tried downloading it externally too, using the same link, but there too it was taking an infinite time.

Can someone please enlighten me what the problem might be and what all steps should I take to solve the problem?

P.S. I have a decent internet connection. I tried downloading some other material and there was no problem with it.

Comment: [here's the snapshot](http://i57.tinypic.com/v457ig.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah it's a pretty big download.  There are instructions here : [How to manually install App Engine in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482085/how-to-manually-install-app-engine-in-android-studio/24497921)

on how to link to a downloaded appengine sdk.

Comment: My point is instead of doing downloading independently and then changing the path ,can't we just change the path from where the studio downloads appengine.

Comment: This [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads) here shows the file size to be 170MB and also download s pretty soon

Comment: It's not studio that is downloading appengine, it's the gradle-appengine-plugin, and that downloads directly from the services at mavenCentral or jCenter depending on your configuration.  You can try configuring a custom repository, but I think it needs a maven descriptor to be discoverable.