# Appengine Sdk for android studio

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

I wish to use GCM for my project, so I followed the standard google docs and added the App engine backend with GCM. It starts the gradle sync which downloads the appengine sdk from `jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.14/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.14.zip` which is taking large time to even start downloading. So I downloaded the appengine sdk externally. I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482085/how-to-manually-install-app-engine-in-android-studio). But still was unable to figure out from the solutions. I am new to android so can you please guide me. I am using Android Studio 1.1.0.

Comment: Do you have any code examples or errors from what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

I think to get start with `Appengine` in `Android Studio`, you can check out with this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzGgdyZIsMk

For note, you can check out this:

https://ajaycs14.wordpress.com/2014/12/27/google-app-engine-backends-with-andriod-client-step-by-step-tutorial/

Also, get the `source code` form here:

https://github.com/ajaycs14/Google-Cloud-App