# Google App Engine: Could not resolve dependencies for configuration: appengineSDK

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

Error:

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':backendContactDatabase:appengineSdk'.
>   Could not download artifact 'appengine-java-sdk.zip (com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18)'
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.18/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.18.zip'.
>   jcenter.bintray.com

I have externally downloaded the 'appengine-java-sdk-1.9.18.zip' file.
Help me out with step-wise changes to be made now (Ex: Which folder to paste this zip file to, Changes to be made in any gradle file etc..) to get my app up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the download timedout when getting from jcenter (it's not a small download). If you want to manually configure your appengine SDK -> [How to manually install App Engine in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482085/how-to-manually-install-app-engine-in-android-studio/24497921)