# Gradle sync with appengine sdk is never ending

Tags: android, google-app-engine

While adding Google Cloud module to an existing android application, gradle sync process downloads the appengine sdk from *http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.14/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.14.zip*. The download process is never ending though the network connectivity is very good.

**Questions :**

1) Is there any way to **check the progress** of the download so as to continue with the development process.

2) I have downloaded the appengine-java sdk seperately from the above website. Is there any way to reference this sdk instead of downloading it?(It could be helpful if you specify the path in which the sdk has to be placed)

[image]

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: there are more than 100MB to download - could really take long

Comment: But it has been more than 3 hours.

Comment: Oh that sounds too long - but might still a possibility when you where hitting a slow server

Comment: Perhaps try on the console to see a bit more what's going on

Comment: You can run the download command from the command line `<gradlew> appengineDownloadSdk`.  That might give you better information on your progress. Alternatively, there is a way to point to your sdk : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482085/how-to-manually-install-app-engine-in-android-studio/24497921

Comment: If you are using android studio, it is better not to download things yourself but to use Gradle to download it. Try restarting your computer and see if that helps.

Comment: Your gradle config file should have an option to select which version of the SDK to use. See if you can make use of `1.9.27`, the latest, rather than `1.9.14` which is hopelessly out of date. Maybe it'll even download in a reasonable time. One way to sanity check the network would be to figure out where you're downloading the file from and run network diagnostics to determine the latency and routing to that location.