# Tell gradle to not to download appengine-java-sdk from remote Jcenter repository, instead use it from local storage on my computer

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, gradle, google-cloud-platform

I am a beginner in android app development and have very little experience with gradle, so excuse me if question is silly...

> I was trying to have my hands on creating a sample backend application
>   with Google app engine, GOOGLE cloud endpoints, and android studio. I
>   created the app and then added google cloud module as mentioned in
>   this tutorial [Google cloud backend tutorial](http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/building-backend-applications-with-google-app-engine-google-cloud-endpoints-and-android-studio),after initial steps,
>   gradle build started but it stuck at downloading google-appengine-sdk,
>   when I checked it was downloading it with relatively very low speed
>   (7-8 KBps), so I downloaded the appengine-java-sdk from google
>   repository and after some research I found that gradle put it in
>   ~/.gradle/appengine-sdk folder, so I put it there.But everytime I try
>   to sync the project it starts downloading it from remote repository.

So my question is

**how do I tell gradle to use appengine-java-sdk(which I have already downloaded) from local storage, considering the fact that downloading appengine-java-sdk using gradle from remote Jcenter repo is no longer an option?**

Comment: I'm not aware of that library but, is it possible it is because your gradle dependency for that library ends in '+'?

Comment: No sir, i have checked it. This is not the case. I have put exact appengine-java-sdk-1.9.28 which gradle is trying to download.The only thing I am not sure about is putting library in the path is valid way or not. If not, then what is the valid way to use library from local storage rather than downloading it from remote repo.

Comment: Does that come in a .jar file? Also, if possible share the web page where it said to put in in `~/.gradle/appengine-sdk` for others. No need to call me sir :) .

Comment: No one is saying to put it in ~/.gradle/appengine-sdk, I am using just my own sense to put it the place where gradle put it after downloading from remote repo, as I think gradle will look in local storage first before trying to download from remote repo, still it just a guess as I am not aware of standard method of doing so.

Its a sdk library and there are lot of Jar files in it, besides other required things.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the gradle download is triggered by the dependency in your buildFile's `dependencies` block. The `downloadSdk` task takes what gradle has cached locally and extracts it into the .gradle folder.

If you really want to use your own downloaded sdk, you can try to set the environment variable `APPENGINE_HOME` or the system property `appengine.sdk.root` pointing to your current Google App Engine SDK installation. It's very similar to what's described here : [How to manually install App Engine in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482085/how-to-manually-install-app-engine-in-android-studio)